# How can I use sscanf to read a string between brackets?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, scanf

I have some code reading a text file and scanning for words between brackets: '[' and ']'.

When I find the line starting with a '[' I read the string with:

```
line[64] = "[word]";
sscanf(line, "[%s]", resource);

printf("%s\n",resource);

==> word]
```

but I always end up with the string+the bracket. How can i format sscanf to only read the string without the bracket at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exclude the `]` from the set of characters the `scanf()` reads:

```
char resource[100];
if (sscanf(line, "[%99[^]]]", resource) != 1) /* error */;

/* same as */
if (sscanf(line, "[" "%99[^]]" "]", resource) != 1) /* error */;
/*          literal   scanset   literal */
```

Comment: Thanks. I was also trying to use a defined characterset with [a-z] but  couldnt make it work.

Comment: I am not much into format strings, but would it not be `%99s`? If you could explain this, ideally with a reference to the standard, you'd definitely have my upvote.

Comment: @Gandaro: your example leaves the closing `]` in the input ("[word]") unaccounted for. Suppose the requirement changes to read two words from "[foo] [bar]" ...

Comment: @phresnel: `"%99s"` reads both the `[` and `]` into the variable. The "%s" conversion skips only whitespace.

Comment: @fazineroso: `sscanf(line, "[%[a-z]]", resource)` should work too. You probably were doing something wrong ...

Comment: @pmg: What I mean: You write `%99`, but I don't know that specifier. I've looked into the standard, but I can't find a format specifier that has only numbers.

Comment: @phresnel See 7.21.6.2 in [the C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). The numbers are there to limit the size read and avoid buffer overflows; the conversion specifier (point 12 in the section of the Standard) is `[`.

Comment: @pmg: A fool I am. Multiple times I scrolled over that one without recognizing it. Virtual +2, because I learned something new today.